# moment.js not properly converting epoch to ISO8601

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I am using moment.js to convert time in ISO8601 format to epoch. However when I convert back the result is not the same. Any ideas?

node.js code

```
var moment = require('moment');
var input ="2014-08-23T15:05:36-07:00";
var a = moment(input,moment.ISO_8601).valueOf();
console.log ("convert ISO8601 to epoch time:" + input + "====>" + a);
var b = moment(parseInt(a)).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ");
console.log ("convert epoch time to ISO8601:" + a + "====>" + b);
```

output

```
convert ISO8601 to epoch time:2014-08-23T15:05:36-07:00====>1408831536000
convert epoch time to ISO8601:1408831536000====>2014-08-23T15:08:00-07:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- You used a format string of `"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ"`.  However `MM` refers to months, not minutes - and `SS` is for the first two decimal places of *fractional* seconds.  If you wanted to provide a format string, it would be `"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"`.  It is case sensitive.
- As mscdex pointed out, you could just use `.format()` without any parameters, as this is the default output format.
- `moment.ISO_8601` is not necessary in this case, as you are only parsing a single format and ISO-8601 is understood by default.
- `parseInt` is also not required.  Moment will understand the value passed in as an integer or a string.

As such, the code can be reduced to:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var input ="2014-08-23T15:05:36-04:00";
var a = moment(input).valueOf();
console.log ("convert ISO8601 to epoch time:" + input + "====>" + a);
var b = moment(a).format();
console.log ("convert epoch time to ISO8601:" + a + "====>" + b);
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use `moment.format()` to get an ISO8601 string instead of passing in a custom format string. Example:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var input ="2014-08-23T15:05:36-04:00";
var a = moment(input,moment.ISO_8601).valueOf();
console.log ("convert ISO8601 to epoch time:" + input + "====>" + a);
var b = moment(parseInt(a)).format();
console.log ("convert epoch time to ISO8601:" + a + "====>" + b);
```

outputs:

```
convert ISO8601 to epoch time:2014-08-23T15:05:36-04:00====>1408820736000
convert epoch time to ISO8601:1408820736000====>2014-08-23T15:05:36-04:00
```